# Conditional operator for odd or even

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that that will find if there's an equal number of odds and even numbers in a given one, it's working great but it want to use conditional operator instead of these 4 rows (the // rows),

I'm getting this:

> Syntax error on token "%", invalid AssignmentOperator

Can someone tell me why? What's wrong?

```
while(number!=0) {
    //if(number%2==0)
    //even++;
    //else
    //odd++;
    number%2==0 ? even++ : odd++;
    number/=10;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate the result of the ternary operator to something: `int dummy = number%2==0 ? even++ : odd++;`. Your initial code looks fine to me to be honest.

Comment: What’s wrong with the good old `if(……) …; else …;`? You may write it into one row as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
number%2==0 ? even++ : odd++;
```

This is not a statement. The result of a ternary must be assigned to something:

```
int x = number % 2 == 0 ? even++ : odd++;
```

However, this is stylistically quite awkward. I would use an `if-else` (i.e., what you originally had) over this pattern. Here you've created a temporary variable that you're never going to reuse, for the sole purpose of using a ternary.

Answer (score 1):

It requires a variable at the left side at where you can place the value after the condition.

```
int tmp = (number%2 == 0)?even++:odd++;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number%2==0 ? even++ : odd++;
```

This statement is not assigning any value to number.As per my knowledge its always recommended for use `if-else` instead of ternary operator.

Because, in ternary operator the false/else part is compulsory to write, where in `if-else` else/false part is optional.

```
  while(number!=0) {
        //if(number%2==0)
        //even++;
        //else
        //odd++;
        int temp= number%2==0 ? even++ : odd++;
        number/=10;

   }
```

Now, `temp` variable is holding the value .